# How do I terminate a msgbox in python? (using python easygui site-package/module)

Tags: python, easygui

I'm a newbie and am having some problems with finding the documentation of how to implement certain commands for the msgbox. One would be how to terminate the box.

Answer (score 0):

[Online Docs](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/download/version_0.95/doc/epydoc/index.html), use `sys.exit(0)` to terminate. If you want to close a specific box I think you'll probably have to graduate to Tk.