# AttributeError: module 'easygui' has no attribute 'msgbox'

Tags: python, easygui

I am trying to use `easygui` for the first time, and I keep getting the error message:

> AttributeError: module 'easygui' has no attribute 'msgbox'

Is there an easy way to fix this?

My code is

```
import easygui as eg 
eg.msgbox("Hello, world!")
```

Comment: Please show all code you have so far

Comment: You'll have to [edit] your question to provide us an [mcve].  Without it, we can't provide a better answer than, "don't do that then".

Comment: You are trying to access a non existent member of some class or module. We won't know how to fix it unless we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could try [`easygui.abouteasygui`](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/api.html#easygui.abouteasygui) to get the version information of whatever your `import easygui` found --- maybe you're importing an older version that didn't have `msgbox`.  It's hard to tell, since there's no historical information in their docs that I can find.  (No "added in version...").

Comment: Given that `easygui` was last updated about 18 months ago, and since most of the questions on SO seem to be answered with variants of "`easygui` can't..." or "...doesn't run on..." or "the docs don't cover _operating\_system_...", it might be easier to skip the "easy" option and try [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html).  It's awkward to use, and not at all easy to learn, but it works, and it comes in the Python standard library.  I'm jumping the gun a bit, but my first impression of `easygui` is [pretty low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731438/4116239).

Comment: It's almost certainly a version issue. The code works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance! - Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is wrong. You need to import the msgbox package from easygui.

You can do it like this:

```
 from easygui import* # this will import all the packages from easygui
```

OR like this:

```
 from easygui import msgbox
 msgbox(your message, title)
```

For more information, please see this link:

> http://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-easygui

Answer (score 0):

Check, please, the name of your program/module/script.  If you used "easygui.py" as a name for your script, then you should change the name to another.

Or you may have another file with the name ('easygui.py') in your current directory.

Or you have installed or created another module with the same name: 'easygui.py'.

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with the script. just change the name of the file other than 'easygui' and clean the cache, then try again pls.